What does QuantizeWrapperV2 actually do?
So I am training this small CNN model which has few Conv2D layers and some MaxPool2D, Activations, Dense, basically the basic layers that Tensorflow provides.
I want it to run on an embedded system which doesn't have lots of space, and cannot make floating point calculations.
Hence I was trying to do a QAT training (Quantize Aware Training) with the model so the weights will be (eventually) quantized to 8-bit and I am using the tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeWrapperV2.
I couldn't understand the parameters count and the actions (mathematically) it does for each type of layer, and I would love to get some help understanding the undocumented math operations given by this API.
Below there is the summary of the same model, once with QAT and once without. there is a difference on the Param # column that I couldn't understand.
Thanks for the help.
Here is the model summary WITHOUT QAT applied:
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 56, 56, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 54, 54, 30)        300       
                                                                 
 activation_3 (Activation)   (None, 54, 54, 30)        0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 27, 27, 30)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 25, 25, 16)        4336      
                                                                 
 activation_4 (Activation)   (None, 25, 25, 16)        0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 12, 12, 16)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 10, 16)        2320      
                                                                 
 activation_5 (Activation)   (None, 10, 10, 16)        0         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d_1   (None, 16)               0         
 (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                        
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 8)                 136       
                                                                 
 activation_6 (Activation)   (None, 8)                 0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
                                                                 
 activation_7 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 7,101
Trainable params: 7,101
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Here is the model summary WITH QAT Applied:
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 56, 56, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 quantize_layer_1 (QuantizeL  (None, 56, 56, 1)        3         
 ayer)                                                           
                                                                 
 quant_conv2d_3 (QuantizeWra  (None, 54, 54, 30)       301       
 pperV2)                                                         
                                                                 
 quant_activation_3 (Quantiz  (None, 54, 54, 30)       3         
 eWrapperV2)                                                     
                                                                 
 quant_max_pooling2d_2 (Quan  (None, 27, 27, 30)       1         
 tizeWrapperV2)                                                  
                                                                 
 quant_conv2d_4 (QuantizeWra  (None, 25, 25, 16)       4337      
 pperV2)                                                         
                                                                 
 quant_activation_4 (Quantiz  (None, 25, 25, 16)       3         
 eWrapperV2)                                                     
                                                                 
 quant_max_pooling2d_3 (Quan  (None, 12, 12, 16)       1         
 tizeWrapperV2)                                                  
                                                                 
 quant_conv2d_5 (QuantizeWra  (None, 10, 10, 16)       2321      
 pperV2)                                                         
                                                                 
 quant_activation_5 (Quantiz  (None, 10, 10, 16)       3         
 eWrapperV2)                                                     
                                                                 
 quant_global_average_poolin  (None, 16)               3         
 g2d_1 (QuantizeWrapperV2)                                       
                                                                 
 quant_dense (QuantizeWrappe  (None, 8)                137       
 rV2)                                                            
                                                                 
 quant_activation_6 (Quantiz  (None, 8)                3         
 eWrapperV2)                                                     
                                                                 
 quant_dense_1 (QuantizeWrap  (None, 1)                14        
 perV2)                                                          
                                                                 
 quant_activation_7 (Quantiz  (None, 1)                1         
 eWrapperV2)                                                     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 7,131
Trainable params: 7,101
Non-trainable params: 30
_________________________________________________________________


QuantizeWrapperV2 quantizes the weights and activations of the keras layer it wraps. This involves converting high-precision weights and activations to lower precision formats. When you apply QAT, the layers are modified to support quantization during training and this results in slightly increasing the number of parameters to manage the quantization process. To learn more about it, please refer this document.
